# Python: Using Pandas to plot more than one series in each subplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colors, subplot

Using python, I have created a pandas dataframe that contains four columns (date, df1, df2, df3). The 'date' series is the index for the dataframe.

I am trying to create two subplots (read: two stacked graphs), that share the 'date' series as the x-axis.

I would like to plot series1 and series 2 on the first subplot, using colors: black and blue.

In the second subplot I would like to plot series3, using the color: red.

Does anybody know how I can go about doing this using pandas or matplotlib?

Thanks in advance!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file1 = "LNQ2014LNV2014"
file2 = "LNV2014LNZ2014"
file3 = "LNQ2014LNV2014LNV2014LNZ2014"

df1 = pd.read_csv("%s.csv" % (file1), index_col = 0)
df1 = df1.drop(df1.columns[[0,1,2,4,5]], axis = 1)
df1.columns = ["%s" % file1]

df2 = pd.read_csv("%s.csv" % (file2), index_col = 0)
df2 = df2.drop(df2.columns[[0,1,2,4,5]], axis = 1)
df2.columns = ["%s" % file2]

df3 = pd.read_csv("%s.csv" % (file3), index_col = 0)
df3 = df3.drop(df3.columns[[0,1,2,4,5]], axis = 1)
df3.columns = ["%s" % file3]

dfresult = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis = 1, join = "inner")

plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(df1, color = "black")
plt.plot(df2, color = "blue")
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(df3, color = "red")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the subplot function. This creates 2 vertically stacked plots like you mentioned:

```
from matplotlib import pylab as pl

pl.subplot(211)
pl.plot(date, series1, color='black')
pl.plot(date, series2, color='blue')
pl.subplot(212)
pl.plot(date, series3, color='red')
pl.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer to this question!  Code-only answers [are discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148274) on Stack Overflow, because a code dump with no context doesn't explain how or why the solution will work, making it impossible for the original poster (or any future readers) to understand the logic behind it.  Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer.